# Display different image based on user info

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a customer management portal I use for customer info, such as carrier, type of device, payment history, etc. When we are creating a new customer and entering all of their info, there is a drop down menu to select what cell phone carrier they are active with.

Once you complete all of the data entry and click submit, all the info gets inserted into mysql, and then it takes you to the customers profile page where it shows all the info you just entered in a neat little layout.

The one thing I would like to change is, depending on what carrier that has been selected during the new customer entry, on the customers profile page I would like to display the logo of that carrier.

I just dont know how to do it, would I use js?

Comment: I am afraid the answer is - you would need to do research and depending on your current technologies used on your project make neccessary adjustments. If your project uses javascript to construct user interface then by all means you will need to use it. If your project has server-side templates for python you would need to edit python scripts. Etc, etc, etc

Comment: most of the portal is built with php and javascript and some jquery. My programmer has been unavailable, and this is a custom built portal. I know how to use basic javascript to do simple things, I just dont know how to display an image based on information entered into a database.  I will do some more research and see what I can figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it sounds like you would probably rather use PHP. You could have a column in the database for carrier. When selecting the $row['carrier'] it can do a little if/else statement for which picture to use. For example:

```
<?php
if($row['carrier'] == "at&t"){
    $carrier_img = "your img here";
}elseif($row['carrier'] == "tmobile"){
    $carrier_img = "your img here";
}
?>
```

and down in the html you could just echo the result:

```
<img src="<?php echo $carrier_img; ?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is verry poor, it's not a kind of answerable question... But no, you shouldn't use JS for it, why would you?. Use your server's processing language to fetch the user's info, then eg. name your images to the possible carrier values, and display it as like `<img src="path/' .carrier. '.jpg" />`.

Comment: would that work if there are different carrier to select? like Verizon, T-Mobile, etc?

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @gomoguy yes, it would, though it depends on the values, you shouldn't hane an image to `at&t.jpg`, see Vexxoz's answer.

Comment: @Olga I answered the only one question he asked. Since he didn't told us what language he can use, I can't give an example. And that's how it works: fetch the data from the database, and depending on it's value, display an image... It can be done in 100 ways, with any language.

Comment: @klenium, exactly - the question is too broad to give a somewhat detailed and usable answer. This is a case where comments come in, to seek detail before anwsering. Also you made a poor point about the fact that OP doesn't need to use JS. What is it based on?